# Speech recognition, words out of dictionary

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm performing word recognition by using a tradional procedure.
I'm extracting MFCC features. Then I'm creating a code book in order to do vector quantization. After that, I train discrete HMM for two words: 1stWrod, 2dWord.

Until now, I have been performing the classification like this:
I estimate the probability in the two trained models of a new audio segment with the proper feature extraction and quantization. I say the audio correspond to the class with the highest probability. That gives me good results.

But any audio segment is classified as any of those tho words, when sometimes it's not. I don't not how to say that is not corresponding to any class. I'm not sure if I could solve that by training another model with all of the other data, because it's very different and I think the model wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy approach would a score normalization.

First, for each word model (`W1` and `W2`) you need to compute the likelihood for a number of true positive test instances.
Then, you can model these likelihoods using a gaussian fit, computing mean value and standard deviation for each word model.
Finally, when it comes to check if an unknown word `wj` belongs to `W1` or `W2`, you just have to normalize its score as follows:

[image: score normalization]

for both model `W1` and `W2`, where `LLj` is the log-likelihood of the `j-th` word test instance.
Any score in the below `-3` means the particular test word cannot be properly model by the model (either W1 or W2) used in the normalization process. If both normalized scores are less than -3, the test word cannot be model by neither `W1` nor `W2`, hence is another word.

You need a *proper* number of true positive test word for each model, in order to estimate properly mean values and standard deviations. Then, how much is a *proper* number, it depends on your actual data.

Comment: I did what you told me, but for any reason, some sounds are giving -Inf and don't let me have the mean. I'm using the Kevin Murphy Library for MATLAB, but this also happend with the built in function in MATLAB.

Comment: If the log-likelihood goes to -Inf it means you have a problem in how you have created the feature vector. It means the model your are currently using doesn't match the data at all. Check if there is any issue with the original audio file (wrong encoding, wrong sample rate, etc), and double check how you perform the feature extraction.